# Resonance effect of amide group

Tags: organic-chemistry

How will an amide group behave while being atrached to a benzene ring?Will it be donating due to lone pair of nitrogen or withdrawing due to carbonyl carbon?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Resonating structures of Benzalamide]

As you can see, the positive charge comes on the benzene ring, therefore **the group draws electron cloud away from the benzene ring.**

**Edit: I have assumed it is attached through the C.**

Sorry about the untidness.

Comment: Thsnks user79161.Can you show me the effect of ester group in a similar way?